# "network error: connection refused", putty error

Tags: putty

I am trying to run `putty` on Windows 7.

I need to run some SSH commands to upgrade Magento. Every time putty gives me this fatal error:

> network error: connection refused

I have even tried to use it through `winSCP`. Note that putty is running fine on my client's side, but for me it's giving me that error every time.

I tried using port 22, 23 and a few others without success. I have also tried with Windows Firewall both enabled and disabled.

Thank you.

Comment: This question sounds more like a possible configuration/setup issue rather than aprogramming related issue. Have a look at putty related issues over on [**SuperUsers.com**](http://superuser.com/search?q=putty+ssh+windows+7+connection+refused) there is questions like [**Can't SSH over Internet**](http://superuser.com/questions/298528/cant-ssh-over-internet) and similar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connection refused on new EC2 Instance putty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467118/connection-refused-on-new-ec2-instance-putty)

Answer (score 3):

Install `open-ssh` or `ssh` in target Linux machine solved my problem .

**Use below commands**:

```
sudo apt install ssh
sudo systemctl status ssh
sudo systemctl enable ssh
```

Answer (score 1):

The following are the list of possibilities of this error:

1) Common cause is - Your IP is blocked or not whitelisted in the server which can be done by editing the file at /etc/csf/csf.conf

2) Disable the windows firewall settings and check..

The above two things should work in most of the cases

3) This is very unusual and when the above two options fails it is very difficult to find the solution

- In this case the traceroute to the server host or IP works usually but putty fails
- port 22 looks normal and working but connection fails and restarting SSH (service ssh restart) also does not work
- reboot or restart the server but still fails
- Adding IP in firewalls or whitelisting the local IP may not workout

This case generally happens when the server is migrated or new server. IP of the old server might be whitelisted locally, but don't have port 22 open, or some other local filtering is occurring for this new IP but not the old server IP..

In this case you need to change the port to some 522 or 530 some unusual port will help in sorting it out.. The same port you have to use for the SFTP connection also .. where as FTP connections works normally..

or you have to whitelist the IP locally or open the TCP in and out to port 22 if you want to use the port 22..