# ssh : Connect to host <myPublicIP> port 22: connection refused

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, cloud

I started learning Amazon Web Services from their documentation (https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/launch-a-virtual-machine/)
I set up an Instance, I get my SSH key, My public IP,
and then I try to ssh into my the instance through command line on my machine as mentioned in their documentation ( stuck at step -3 of the documentation )

```
chmod 400 /path/my-key-pair.pem
```

this worked fine..

```
ssh -i /path/my-key-pair.pem ec2-user@my-public-IP-address
```

but when I try this I get an error:

```
ssh : Connect to host <myPublicIP> port 22: connection refused
```

I researched most of the answers, There were two possible solutions: Either reinstall the SSH ( did that too) or some asked for ssh -v

here are the result :

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu0.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to <MypublicIP> [<MypublicIP>] port 22.
debug1: connect to address <MypublicIP> port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host <MypublicIP> port 22: Connection refused
```

and then nothing.

Any suggestions or Useful Links are welcomed.
I appreciate the effort for linking this question to [Connection refused on new EC2 Instance putty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467118/connection-refused-on-new-ec2-instance-putty)
Although that didn't work either, But PuTTY is used for Windows, I'd like this to work on Ubuntu.
Thank you

Comment: check your security group of your instance and make sure to allow inbound traffic on port 22

Comment: @FrédéricHenri Did that too, Added my IP address in the Security group, Same error :( Thanks for the help though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connection refused on new EC2 Instance putty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467118/connection-refused-on-new-ec2-instance-putty)

Comment: @KarenB Thank you for the effort, But I'm using Ubuntu, though I tried it on Windows machine too last night, and it gave the same error : 'Connection Refused', further help would be really appreciated.

Comment: As the answer in the question says, it's a security group issue on the EC2 side.  You need to configure your firewall rules in AWS.  It's not a client-side issue.

Comment: @KarenB I have done it too, Added my local server IP address explicitly in the security group of the Amazon Instance ( both the default and the one for my instance )

Comment: @KarenB It has to be client side issue, because I just found out that if I try `ssh -T git@github.com` I get the error : `ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection refused`

Comment: There's a firewall between you and the outside world blocking 22/TCP.  Start with your local router and work outward.

Comment: @KarenB Thank you for the prompt response, But I'm a little new to all this, could you provide me with a little more details on 'Start with your local router and work outward' 
Here are some details: I checked `nmap localhost` and I got this:
`Host is up (0.00021s latency).`

`Not shown: 996 closed ports`
`PORT     STATE SERVICE`
`22/tcp   open  ssh`
`80/tcp   open  http`
`631/tcp  open  ipp`
`3306/tcp open  mysql`

`Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.06 seconds`

Comment: Debugging network routing issues is not an  appropriate topic for Stack Overflow.  Try asking on Server Fault or Super User.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing similar short of issue, You need to put your network IP in security group. Try allowing Traffic from Anywhere in Security group and then connect. If that works put your network IP in AWS security group.

Comment: Thank You for the response, 2 people have suggested that on this post already, still no luck.
Any thoughts on Port checking and other things would be appreciated.